# Trying to equate a struct[array].variable to a character it matches from an input/out

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io, struct

So I'm trying to get the file to equate the struct type (in here Patient[i].BType == 'A'). Logic behind it is if that struct in the file reads A, output something. Its giving me errors of: 
error: no match for 'operator==' in 'Patient[i].Person::BType == 'A''
error: no match for 'operator==' in 'Donor[i1].Person::BType == 'A''

Any idea on how to match that type of struct array with a specific character it holds?

```
struct Person{
string surname;
string BType;
string organ;
int age;
int year, ID;
} Patient[50], Donor[50];
```

Then the code in interest is:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for (i1 = 0; i1 < 5; i1++){
        if ((Patient[i].BType == 'A') && (Donor[i1].BType == 'A')){
            cout << Patient[i].surname << "  " << Donor[i1].surname;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: all 3 answers worked. Thanks. Stupid mistake on my part, clearly you can tell I'm a novice at this. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing a `std::string` with a single `char`, change

```
if ((Patient[i].BType == 'A') && (Donor[i1].BType == 'A'))
```

to

```
if ((Patient[i].BType == "A") && (Donor[i1].BType == "A"))
```

With the double quote, `"A"` is a C-style string, while single quote `'A'`is a single `char`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the single quotes to double quotes:

```
(Patient[i].BType == "A") && (Donor[i1].BType == "A")
```

`Btype` is of type `std::string`, and can be compared with string literals (double quotes), but not of objects of type `char` (single quotes).

You can find [more information here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) which lists all the available `operator==`.

Answer (score 0):

BType is a string. You should compare it with a string "A" not a char 'A'.